# Safari HTML5 video discolored/dark

Tags: html, video, safari

The video plays just fine in every browser, and I use the standard 3-codec approach. On every other browser, the video "melts" into the white background intentionally, but in Safari, the video appears gray and ruins the effect - any ideas why?

Homepage: http://www.mybloodfirst.com

Simplified test page: http://new.mybloodfirst.com/videotest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JavaScript Progress Monitor</title>
</head>

  <body>
     <div align=center>
        <video preload="none" autoplay loop>
            <source src="images/home-surgeon.webm" type='video/webm;' />
            <source src="images/home-surgeon.ogv" type='video/ogg;' />
            <source src="images/home-surgeon.mp4" type='video/mp4;' />
            <img src="images/home-surgeon.jpg">
        </video>
      </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Additional testing with ordering the sources..

http://new.mybloodfirst.com/videotest2.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested, but perhaps the issue has to do with the ordering of your `<source>` tags.  Try putting the mp4 one first.  I am unfamiliar with the exact specifics of WebM and OGG support in Safari, but I would guess it isn't nearly as good as MP4.

Comment: Additional testing like you recommended: http://new.mybloodfirst.com/videotest2.html hmm.. this one's a real stumper!

Comment: Hm, it's working fine for me in Safari 5.1.3, OS X 10.7.3. Chrome 17 also works fine fwiw. Perhaps it is a known issue with the version of Safari you are using? Maybe it's just a Windows version Safari issue?  Do you have any Safari extensions installed that could be causing the issue?

Comment: That's good! Here's what I'm seeing - http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/62/21391417.jpg/ Safari 5.1.2 Windows 7 64

Comment: Try using something like http://mediaelementjs.com/ which will provide graceful fallback for HTML5 video. Perhaps it can handle this case. Failing that, it sounds like a bug in Windows Safari so try Google and the Apple support forums armed with that proof. Another plausible possibility is a CSS or `<video>` tag formatting issue.  Finally, maybe it's an oddity of the particular encoding of the video you are using.  Try re-encoding it using some different tools maybe that will resolve it.